# how to change default api route path in laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, api, routes

I just want to change route path for api which routes/api.php to routes/Routes/api.routes.php

this is RouteServiceProvider.php

```
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //

        parent::boot();
    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function map()
    {
        $this->mapApiRoutes();

        $this->mapWebRoutes();
        $this->mapProjectApiRoutes();


        //
    }

    /**
     * Define the "web" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    protected function mapProjectApiRoutes(){
        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware(['api', 'RequestEncrypt', 'ApiKey'])
            ->namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Api')
            ->group(base_path('routes/Routes/api.routes.php'));
    }
    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    }

    /**
     * Define the "api" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes are typically stateless.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api')
             ->middleware('api')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
}
```

this is what i did in RouteServiceProvider.php

please check below image i'm getting this error

[image]

I'm using laravel 5.8
please help.

Comment: find out what the error is in the error message which will include the line number and fix it

Comment: this error I'm getting BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory::api does not exist. in file D:\XAMPP\htdocs\laravelFresh5.8\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\Macroable.php on line 104

Comment: look at the stacktrace, probably the next step in it (if not keep going through the trace until you get to your code) and it will have the line number where you are trying to use the method that doens't exist, `ResponseFactory` does not have a method named `api`